# Assign array of values to array of variables

Tags: ruby, local-variables

I have array of variables like

`a,b,c = [10,20,30]`

and

`values = [1, 2, 3]`

and assinged variables a,b,c to d like below

`d = [a,b,c]`

Is there any way to assign values to variables without iterating, like 
`d = values` so that I get the following?

a = 1, b = 2, c = 3

Comment: `a,b,c = values`

Comment: You wrote that you have an array of variables, but you cannot. `[a, b, c]` is not an array of variables. They are actually some values that are referred to by the respective variables.

Comment: _"Initially i have ... Now, I have ..."_ – I don't follow. What is it that you have and what is it that you want? i.e. what's your actual input and your expected result?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One more thing: why do you call `a,b,c = [10,20,30]` an "array of variables"? `[10,20,30]` is an array, but an array of _numbers_. `a, b, c = ...` on the other hand is an _assignment_. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: And regarding _"... any way to assign values to variables without iterating"_ – how would you solve it **with** iterating? An attempted solution could shed some light on the problem.

Comment: `d = (a,b,c = [1,2,3])` should do this for you although I am not sure why you would need to do this when `d == [1,2,3]` but the opposite would also work `a,b,c = d = [1,2,3]`

Comment: Without knowing the actual problem, I have a suspicion that replacing the `Array` with a `Hash` is probably the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
a,b,c = values
a #=> 1
b #=> 2
c #=> 3
```

For the updated portion:
Having `d = [a,b,c]` and thinking of assigning `d = values` and expecting a,b,c to change wouldn't work, because `d = [a,b,c]` is an assignment, `d` is set as `[10,20,30]`.

Probably, something like this may help in understanding how you can achieve this:

a, b, c = [10, 20, 30]

```
values = [1,2,3]
d = -> (x) { a, b, c = x }
a #=> 10
b #=> 20
c #=> 30
d.call values
a #=> 1
b #=> 2
c #=> 3
```

`d` in above case is a `lambda`, they are named block which can be invoked later. They bind with the variables in current scope, so they can change them when invoked (by `d.call`)

Comment: What happened with `d`?

Comment: OP has changed the question from https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35816090-c8a1-4132-ac82-ff01331bcf27/view-source .

Comment: I know. The OP only changed the variable name from `variables` to `d`. What happened with `variables`, then?